# Simple use of the chain rule

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I have the following problem where I feel I am missing something obvious:

I have the function $f(x)=-\ln(x+x^2)$ with $x>0$ and I wish to find the derivative. By using the chain rule I get
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x}
$$

But the solution guide I am looking at gives the derivative
$$
-\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1+x}\right)
$$

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Combine the bottom expression into a single fraction to get your version (anyway the method by which they probably got their answer is they first split up the logarithm, using the fact that log of a product is sum of logs: $\log(x^2+x)=\log x +\log(x+1).$ now one can differentiate each term separately.)

Comment: Hint: Partial fractions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Was there some other way to get the derivative or did they most likely split it into the last expression after getting the same thing I did?

Comment: they started by splitting the logs into $-\ln x-\ln(1+x)$

Comment: I.e., $-\ln(x+x^2) =- \ln (x(1+x)) = -(\ln x + \ln(1+x)) ...$.  But your answer is entirely correct, as both solutions you present are equivalent.

Comment: Do notice that this is as a result of applying [the partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) to the derivative, which is a very handy tool, that has even greater importance when dealing with integrals of polynomial fractions.

Comment: @BftA  If you understand the equivalence, Please feel free to write an answer to your question, given the hints!

Answer (score 1):

###### 1) The Derivative of f(x):

a) Definition of f(x) and f'(x):
$$
    f(x)=-\ln (x+x^2)
$$
$$
    f'(x)=\frac {d}{dx} (-\ln (x+x^2))
$$

b) Chain Rule Definition:

$$
\frac {d}{dx} (h(g(x))=h'(g(x))+g'(x)
$$

c) Finding f'(x):

$$
    f'(x)=\frac {d}{dx} (-\ln (x+x^2))
$$
$$
h(x)=-\ln(x)
$$
$$
h'(x)=-1/x
$$
$$
g(x)=x+x^2
$$
$$
g'(x)=1+2x
$$
$$
f'(x)=\frac {d}{dx} (-\ln(x+x^2))=\frac{-1}{x+x^2}(1+2x)=-\frac{1+2x}{x+x^2}
$$

###### 2) Partial Fraction Decomposition:

a) Define new function n(x):
$$
n(x)=\frac{1+2x}{x+x^2}
$$
$$
f'(x)=-n(x)
$$
       b) Partial Fraction:
$$
n(x)=\frac{1+2x}{(x)(1+x)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{1+x}=\frac{A(1+x)+B(x)}{(x)(1+x)}
$$
$$
n(x)=\frac{A+Ax+Bx}{(x)(1+x)}=\frac{x(A+B)+1(A)}{(x)(1+x)}
$$
$$
x(A+B)=2x, \:\:  1(A)=1
$$
$$
A+B=2, \:\:  1(A)=1
$$
$$
A=1, \:\:  B=1
$$
$$
 n(x)=\frac{1+2x}{x+x^2}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{1+x}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1+x}
$$
       c) Final Answer:
$$
f'(x)=-n(x)
$$

$$
n(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1+x}
$$
$$
f'(x)=-\left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1+x} \right)
$$

Hope this helps,
Good luck

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle-\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x}=-\frac{x+(x+1)}{x(x+1)}=-\bigg(\frac{x}{x(x+1)}+\frac{x+1}{x(x+1)}\bigg)=-\bigg(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+1}\bigg)$